# Get gitk to show full tag names

Tags: git, gitk

Is it possible to get `gitk` to show the full tag names instead of a shortened version. When I use long names I just see "tag...":

[image]

Comment: You can use the `File / List references` or `F2`  to open list of branches and tags. The full name is displayed there. Maybe it is good enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant code, from /usr/bin/gitk in my Ubuntu Xenial machine:

```
set marks {}
set ntags 0
set nheads 0
set singletag 0
set maxtags 3
set maxtagpct 25
set maxwidth [expr {[graph_pane_width] * $maxtagpct / 100}]
set delta [expr {int(0.5 * ($linespc - $lthickness))}]
set extra [expr {$delta + $lthickness + $linespc}]

if {[info exists idtags($id)]} {
    set marks $idtags($id)
    set ntags [llength $marks]
    if {$ntags > $maxtags ||
        [totalwidth $marks mainfont $extra] > $maxwidth} {
        # show just a single "n tags..." tag
        set singletag 1
        if {$ntags == 1} {
            set marks [list "tag..."]
        } else {
            set marks [list [format "%d tags..." $ntags]]
        }
        set ntags 1
    }
}
```

Given that, the options that I see are

- to increase the width of the panel, by moving the author divider further over to the right
- to hack that code, e.g. by increasing maxtagpct so that the tag name is allowed to occupy more of the available width.

I don't think there's anything there that is controlled by an already exposed configuration setting.

Comment: Expanding the pane full width refused to display some tags for me - even single tags? I just commented out the lines below `# show just a single "n tags..." tag` and now all the tags are expanded.

Answer (score 7):

Expand the pane and hit Shift+F5 to redraw the pane. When there is more room to display the tag it should spell it out. I know it probably seems like you have enough room, but give it more.

Comment: Manual redraws? Yikes this UI is "special"